# Return value optimization not working for const unique_ptr member?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, unique-ptr

I have a class Whole that holds an object of a class Part via a unique_ptr. Since I do not provide a copy-constructor for Whole the copy-constructor is deleted, because of the unique_ptr member. Here is the code:

```
class Part {
};

class Whole {
public:
    Whole(std::unique_ptr<Part> part) : part(std::move(part)) {
    }
private:
    const std::unique_ptr<Part> part; //yields error later!
    //std::unique_ptr<Part> part; //ok!
};
```

I would like to create a Whole instance via a factory function called build()

```
Whole build() {
    auto part = std::unique_ptr<Part>{new Part{}};
    return Whole{std::move(part)};
}
```

which I want to use like this:

```
int main() {
    auto whole = build();
}
```

This works as long as the unique_ptr to the Part member of Whole is not declared const. As far as I understand this is due to the return value optimization which prevents the creation and copy of temporaries. However,
if I declare Whole::part as const my compiler complains that the deleted copy-constructor is invoked. Why is it not possible to use the const declaration or is there a problem with this code anyway ?

I am using the GNU compiler version:
    (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4

Comment: Copy elision is not mandatory.

Comment: Moving object modifies existing object. And by marking member const, you explicitely set it as not modifiable.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `std::unique_ptr<const Part> part; `?

Comment: There is an implicit move constructor. It's not to do with copy elision.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`const std::unique_ptr` disallow move constructor of class `Whole`.

so `auto whole = build();` is invalid. (even if the call would be elided, the call should be valid)

With C++17, we have guaranteed copy elision which remove that restriction, making code correct.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Is it bad practice to have a std::unique_ptr member and not provide a custom copy/move etc. constructor ? It seems that one has to remember not declare and members const such that the move construction remains possible.

Comment: If you have `std::unique_ptr`, then copy constructor is not generated (as the one from `std::unique_ptr` is deleted), the move constructor is still generated. So class is correctly usable. It would be more readable IMO to explicitly default the move (`Whole(Whole&&)= default;`) and delete the copy (`Whole(const Whole&)= delete;`) (and same for assignment).

Comment: @tabata -san, the copy ctor is off the point here and your edition is misleading. [copy ctor is disallowed even when the OP's code well works because `unique_ptr` must be uniquely-owned.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7OezDSPU9rsGy8lB) `build()` returns rvalue and then `auto whole = build()` calls the **move ctor** of `Whole`. But `const` disallows **move ctor** because it changes `Whole::part` to `nullptr`. Thus the compilation fails. This is what Jarod42 said. BTW, from C++17, RVO is guaranteed in this case and the [original code becomes fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YNUw78kBZRzSss2F).

Comment: Technically, there is no copy elision (RVO) in this case in C++17. Instead, there is no temporary materialized that would be moved-from and `whole` is constructed directly. Consequently, the program is fine in C++17 **even if the move constructor is deleted**: https://wandbox.org/permlink/QXZgSfjKHkhJOoxc.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/xTaz63z68